# htaccess re-route Public directory to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I have:

```
public/
-- index.php
-- my_subdir/
---- index.php
```

I simply want to re-route to my_subdir.

(why? because my_subdir contains my new joomla website.)

**EDIT, to explain why all the other solutions were not working** ... I have been working on this for a couple of hours, and nothing worked. Even the accepted answer here did not initially work. The problem was Not the many solutions provided by google, but rather that I had conflicting rules/conditions.

So here is an example of what I had that was not working (the stuff to the right of the arrows is WHAT I needed to get everything working):

```
RewriteEngine on

<<<< RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^111\.111\.111\.111 
######## my ip address for testing 
########   because this was not originally included, 
########     apparently I was being redirected to maintenance.html ...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ 
RewriteRule $ /maintenance.html [R=302]

######## thus by the time the script/server got to this line
########   I was actually at maintenance.html,
########     and so this next condition did not apply to me
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir
RewriteRule ^.*$ /my_subdir/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Why don't you set `public/my_subdir` as the document root? Why don't you delete the old contents and replace them with the new content?

Comment: oswald, I do not know how to set the subdir as the doc. root.

Comment: It depends on the web server software that you are using. The Apache HTTP Server has a [DocumentRoot directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot), that can be set in the main configuration or a virtual host. If you use Plesk Panel or other software to manage your web server configuration, such software often comes with a GUI frontend that allows you to set the document root.

Comment: unfortunately the webhost does not provide ANY control panel type ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same directory structure below `my_subdir`, you can simply rewrite everything with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir
RewriteRule ^.*$ /my_subdir/$0 [L]
```

If you want to redirect instead, i.e. make the new URL visible in the browser, you must also add the [`R`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /my_subdir/$0 [R,L]
```

Comment: Olaf, I had actually come across a couple of your other responses earlier today ... they did not work, and neither did this ... so I decided to look at the other conditions and rules in my htaccess, and found that other conditions were getting in the way ... I will edit my original post to indicate what was causing the problem. Long story short: your answer does work (but probably so did your other solutions on other similar posts had I not had the conflicting rules) ... thanks.